# django template view nested list

Tags: django, list, templates, indexing

i made a nested list and from that id like to make a table in my template

list looks something like

```
ground_skills_available = [[category1, [skill1, skill2, skill3]], [category1, [skill1, skill2]]]
```

Now i want to list it that you got category with below the items, next category and other items. Problem is, i have no clue about hot to show only category, instead of category +all items, since you cant seem to use the index of a list?

Can someone please help me out?

```
<table>
    {% for categories in ground_skills_available %}
        {% for category in categories %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ category }}</td>
        </tr>
            {% for skill in category %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ skill.name }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your outer loop to

```
{% for category, skills in ground_skills_available %}
```

This technique is described in the [Django for loop docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#for).

On the first iteration of the loop, this will take the list `[category1, [skill1, skill2, skill3]`, and assign

```
category = category1
skills = [skill1, skill2, skill3]
```

You can then display `{{ category }}`, and loop through `skills`.

Putting that together, you have:

```
<table>
    {% for category, skills in ground_skills_available %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ category }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% for skill in skills %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ skill.name }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Ill take a look at this one,  never hurts to know more possible answers for 1 question :)

Answer (score 2):

`{% if forloop.index == 1 %} ... some code ... {% endif %}`

or

`{% if forloop.index0 == 0 %} ... some code ... {% endif %}`

Expectation:

```
{% for categories in ground_skills_available %}

    {% for category in categories %}
    {% if forloop.first %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ category }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% else %}
        {% for skill in category %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ skill.name }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
     {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, i was just about to ask how i should implement it cause i couldnt get it working. But this works perfectly