# Django Template :: How to Use POP() in django template

Tags: python, html, django

In Below code, am iterating through 2 list. users and roles, where I want to print first element from the roles list for the first element from the user.
user = ['abc','cde']
roles = [[1,2,3] , [4,5,6]]

for user 'abc' roles should be printed as 1,2,3 only. but am getting all roles for 'abc' user.

```
<table>
    {% for u in users %}
    <tr>
        {% for r in roles.0 %}
                
        <th><b>{{ u }}</b></th>
        <td><b>{{ r }}</b></td>
                
        {% endfor %}
        {{ roles.pop.0 }}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Can someone help me understanding that why the {{ roles.pop.0 }} is not deleting first element in the roles list?

Comment: Did you try to access all roles to loop in it by using ```roles``` instead of ```roles.0```?

Comment: No buddy, {% for r in roles.0 %} am using this so it will iterate through the first element [1,2,3] of roles list [ [1,2,3] , [4,5,6] ]. And when the iteration completes, the first element [1,2,3] should be deleted  from roles list. So for next iteration, roles list will be [ [4,5,6] ].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django template view nested list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20313515/django-template-view-nested-list)

Comment: Yes, this is what i was looking for. Like not exactly but it gave me the IDEA. I created one list instead of 2 different lists as shown in above link.